# Check sas disk using this connector

Tags: hard-drive, sata, sas

Hi gyus so i have 2 SAS disk at home (IBM AND DELL IN THE IMAGE)and in my work i found this **sas to sata connector** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1Kc9.jpg)
I want to check if this 2 SAS work or no so i did connect this two to my z230 workstation using that connector and booted with clonezilla live usb
But **lsblk** show nothing
So does this mean this sas is died or my z230 doesn't talk with sas even with connector

Note : i did check the connector work fine he was used to attache SAS DISK TO xw8600 workstation (disk that have green plastic in the right work with this connector )[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wF2TX.jpg)

Comment: A SATA controller cannot talk to SAS drives. No adapter could enable that. Do you perhaps have a link to the full adapter description?

Comment: So from you answer i get that somme workstation have sas/sata comtroller (like the hp xw8600) but other don't like mine hp z230